# Powering a redstone torch on a block adjacent to a redstone lamp without powering the lamp

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Would it be possible to power the redstone torch in this configuration without powering the redstone lamp?

[image: Screenshot of a redstone torch on a block adjacent to a redstone lamp in Minecraft]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume by "powering the redstone torch" you mean to turn it off. The torch checks if the block where it is attached is powered. The redstone lamp checks if any adjacent block is powered. If the black wool is powered, both the lamp and the torch will be "activated" - the lamp lit and the torch off. If the black wool is not powered, the lamp will be off (assuming no other adjacent power sources to the lamp) and the torch - on.

So no, you cannot power the torch without also powering the lamp.

There might be a (quite complicated) way to achieve the state "torch off, lamp off" once by suppressing block updates but that won't work for a redstone contraption, any block update of the lamp will turn it on.

Comment: only thing I can think of is torch burnout, but as you said, as soon as the black wool gets an update, it will reset.